# Iterating through directories with Python

Tags: python, directory

I need to iterate through the subdirectories of a given directory and search for files. If I get a file I have to open it and change the content and replace it with my own lines.

I tried this:

```
import os

rootdir ='C:/Users/sid/Desktop/test'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        f=open(file,'r')
        lines=f.readlines()
        f.close()
        f=open(file,'w')
        for line in lines:
            newline = "No you are not"
            f.write(newline)
        f.close()
```

but I am getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "An error" - any error in particular?

Comment: @DanielRoseman He's not supposed to. Code is right.

Comment: Please could you explain a little about what you hope to do with the files / directories once you get the walk through them working as intended? Also please provide error details.

Comment: Basically i have a root directory in which i have some sub directories.In these sub directories i have files. So i have lets say cool.txt file in one of these sub directories, then i want to open this cool.txt file read all the lines and replace all the lines with "No you are not".

Comment: The error message that im getting is that the file cool.txt is not found. In my test folder i have an other folder called src and in the src folder i have another folder called main, in this folder i have cool.txt

Comment: can you just write the error in the question? its beyond annoying and unnecessary to have to read through the comments to find it.

Comment: over a year later I can't believe I'm back requesting for the error to be posted? @Wolf

Comment: The question is anwsered etc, but the error code you will get from this is: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.xml'.

As seen in the marked anwser he had to give the absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 460, accepted):

The actual walk through the directories works as you have coded it. If you replace the contents of the inner loop with a simple `print` statement you can see that each file is found:

```
import os
rootdir = 'C:/Users/sid/Desktop/test'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(subdir, file))
```

Comment: C:/Users/sid/Desktop/test\src\app/cool.txt
C:/Users/sid/Desktop/test\src\app/woohoo.txt 
Ya in the open statement of my code, i think i have to give the absolute path to the file. 

import os
rootdir ='C:/Users/spemmara/Desktop/test/src/app/'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
            f=open(subdir+'/'+ file,'r')
            lines=f.readlines()
            f.close()
            f=open(subdir+'/'+file,'w')
            for line in lines:
                newline = "hey i know"
                f.write(newline)
            f.close()
    
Thanks man. Its solved

Comment: Sir, I am getting IsADIrectoryError

Answer (score 37):

Another way of returning all files in subdirectories is to use [the `pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html#), introduced in Python 3.4, which provides an object oriented approach to handling filesystem paths (Pathlib is also available on Python 2.7 via [the pathlib2 module on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/)):

```
from pathlib import Path

rootdir = Path('C:/Users/sid/Desktop/test')
# Return a list of regular files only, not directories
file_list = [f for f in rootdir.glob('**/*') if f.is_file()]

# For absolute paths instead of relative the current dir
file_list = [f for f in rootdir.resolve().glob('**/*') if f.is_file()]
```

Since Python 3.5, the `glob` module also supports recursive file finding:

```
import os
from glob import iglob

rootdir_glob = 'C:/Users/sid/Desktop/test/**/*' # Note the added asterisks
# This will return absolute paths
file_list = [f for f in iglob(rootdir_glob, recursive=True) if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

The `file_list` from either of the above approaches can be iterated over without the need for a nested loop:

```
for f in file_list:
    print(f) # Replace with desired operations
```

Comment: What is preferable here for Python 3.6?

Comment: @PhoenixDev I haven't heard of one approach being recommended over the other in general. I prefer using `pathlib` myself, mostly because I like  the object oriented methods-syntax. There are other differences, such as the path library returns specific path classes rather than strings, and the available functions differ between the libraries (e.g. `os.path.expanduser('~')` vs `Path.home()`). Browse through the documentation and see which approach you prefer.

Comment: Instead of adding `**` in the glob pattern, you can use [`rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob).

Comment: In your code, what exactly is `rootdir_glob` for? O.o Is it just a full path example? BTW: short version: `import os, glob` + `file_list = [f for f in glob.iglob('**/*', recursive=True) if os.path.isfile(f)]`

Comment: @jave.web Good catch, I believe I meant to use it in the glob so it is equivalent to the first pathlib example. Updated.

Comment: @joelostblom oh, I suggest also using the `os` for creating crossplatform paths :) - anyways based on this idea of yours I've today created a little tool to count all files in **N** directory trees and their sizes, so you can quickly do some basic integrity pre-check - I've published it on https://ideone.com/4pu1qs - there are some "typos" in the prints() but otherwise it's working as a charm :)

Comment: @jave.web Definitely agree, I just used the same as in the question here, otherwise I prefer pathlib's `/` approach. Will check out the link!

Answer (score 27):

From python >= [3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) onward, you can use `**`, [`glob.iglob(path/**, recursive=True)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) and it seems the most *pythonic* solution, i.e.:

```
import glob, os

for filename in glob.iglob('/pardadox-music/**', recursive=True):
    if os.path.isfile(filename): # filter dirs
        print(filename)
```

Output:

```
/pardadox-music/modules/her1.mod
/pardadox-music/modules/her2.mod
...
```

---

Notes:

1. **[glob.iglob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob)**

   > `glob.iglob(pathname, recursive=False)`
   >
   > Return an iterator which yields the same values as `glob()` without actually storing them all simultaneously.
2. If recursive is `True`, the pattern `'**'` will match any files and
   zero or more `directories` and `subdirectories`.
3. If the directory contains files starting with `.` they won’t be matched by default. For example, consider a directory containing `card.gif` and `.card.gif`:

   ```
   >>> import glob
   >>> glob.glob('*.gif') ['card.gif'] 
   >>> glob.glob('.c*')['.card.gif']
   ```
4. You can also use `rglob(pattern)`,
   which is the same as calling `glob()` with `**/` added in front of the given relative pattern.

Comment: This _pythonic_ solution doesn't list hidden files (aka dotfiles) while the accepted one does.

Comment: @ashrasmun What you mention is well explained in https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html