# Looping through all files in a folder and appending a random number to each row in each file using Python

Tags: python, loops, file-io, apache-pig

I am using Pig to generate an output. I would like to randomly assign the output to 2 groups.
As some of you are aware, Pig outputs files in the format part-m-00000 or part-r-00000 into a folder.
I would like to iterate through all the files in an output folder and assign every row a 0 or 1 randomly.

I have the portion of code for the assignment:

```
     with open('part-r-00000','r') as csvinput:
with open('output2.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

    all = []
    for row in reader:
        row.append(randint(0,1))
        all.append(row)

    for row in reader:
         all.append(row)

    writer.writerows(all)
```

This definitely works.
I also have sample input and output:

```
    Sample input:
    0,1,2,1,4,3,3,4,1,1
    2,3,4,1,0,0,1,2,1,1
    0,2,3,1,0,2,3,1,1,1

    Sample output:
    0,1,2,1,4,3,3,4,1,1,0
    2,3,4,1,0,0,1,2,1,1,0
    0,2,3,1,0,2,3,1,1,1,1
```

However, I need to find out how many files are in the folder and add another loop to loop through each file.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) to list all the files in the current directory, or optionally include a path if you want to scan a separate directory. You can then iterate through the list of files:

```
import os

filelist = os.listdir()

for file in filelist:
    # do your stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just iterate over all the files ([`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)) in the current directory ([`os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)):

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    # do your stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
for f in os.listdir('/path/to/directory'):
    # do something with f
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work with sub directories:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for file in files:
        # subdir+'/'+file would be the name of each file
```

edit:
root would be the full path to the folder holding these files

[Iterating through directories with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587118/python-iterating-through-directories)