# Python - loop through a directory and set a variable to a filename to be manipulated

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through a directory and filename into a variable to be manipulated.

Example:

Dir contains:

stuff.txt
home.txt
...
specs.txt

```
for loop:
     var = [filenames in the dir such as stuff,home,spec..]
     print hash(var)
```

Would it be possible to include sub directories?

Comment: What code did you write ? What errors arise  ?

Comment: You might find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587118/python-iterating-through-directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with something like this using [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir):

```
import os
your_dir = '/home/...' # Dir path

for filename in os.listdir(your_dir):
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        print filename
        do_something(filename)
```

With `do_something` being you hash function and so on.