# Select files from specific directories

Tags: python, directory, path, glob

I am trying to loop through a list of subdirectories, and perform two related operations:

- Only select subdirectories that match a certain pattern, and save part of that name
- Read a file in that subdirectory

I have tried adapting the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587118/iterating-through-directories-with-python) but am having trouble opening only certain subdirectories. I know I can do this recursively, where I loop through every file, and pull its parent directory using `Path.parent`, but this would also go into the directories I am not interested in.

My file structure looks like:

```
002normal
|- names.txt
|- test.txt
002custom
|- names.txt
|- test.txt
```

I would like only the directories ending in "normal". I'll then read the file named "names.txt" in that directory. I have tried something like the below, without luck.

```
import os
root_dir = "/Users/adamg/IM-logs"
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    for f in files:
        print(subdir)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `dirs` list in-place to filter out any subdirectories with names not ending with `'normal'` so that `os.walk` won't traverse into them:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    dirs[:] = (name for name in dirs if name.endswith('normal'))
    if 'names.txt' in files:
        with open(os.path.join(subdir, 'names.txt')) as file:
            print(os.path.basename(subdir), file.read())
```

Excerpt from the documentation of `os.walk`:

> When `topdown` is `True`, the caller can modify the `dirnames` list in-place
>   (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse
>   into the subdirectories whose names remain in `dirnames`; this can be
>   used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even
>   to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames
>   before it resumes `walk()` again.

Comment: I like this, it's very elegant. The 2nd-to-last line needs to be `with open(os.path.join(root_dir, subdir, 'names.txt'), 'r') as f:` though

Comment: Also, how do extract the directory name, e.g. "002normal", assuming there are other directories above it?

Comment: Ah indeed. I've updated my answer to join `subdir` with `names.txt` (no need for `root_dir` by the way). The output also now includes the extraction of the base name of the sub-directory by calling `os.path.basename`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
root_dir = "/Users/adamg/IM-logs"
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    if str(subdir).endswith("normal"):
        for file in files:
            if str(file).startswith("names"):
                print(os.path.basename(subdir), file)
                f = open(os.path.join(root_dir,subdir,file), "r") 
                print(f.read())
```

That's how you can do it with your file structure. First you check if any subdir ends with "normal" and if it does you can check the content in the file. Also you have to build the path to the file so that you can read the file with `os.path.join`

In case you have multiple subdirectories of unknown depth you have to do something with while, but as long as the directory which contains names.txt ends with normal it works.

Comment: Thanks. How do extract the directory name, e.g. "002normal", assuming there are other directories above it?

Comment: as told by blhsing already you can use os.path.basename(subdir). But I will add it as well.