# How to iterate folders to get content in first subdirectories?

Tags: python

I want to iterate subdirectories within a directory and get all of the `config.json` files at the root of each subdirectory.  I am having trouble with stopping the walk function at the first subdirectory.  An example of my folder structure is `//abc001/e$/Intepub/wwwroot/Apps/Dev/Region-1` is the `rootdir` while I want to get config.jsons out of folders like this `//abc001/e$/Intepub/wwwroot/Apps/Dev/Region-1/website1/config.json` `//abc001/e$/Intepub/wwwroot/Apps/Dev/Region-1/website2/config.json`
`//abc001/e$/Intepub/wwwroot/Apps/Dev/Region-1/website3/config.json`

Here is the code that I have been working with; it returns all folders within the `rootdir` and gives me an `IOError`. How do I stop the iteration and resolve the IOError?

```
import os
rootdir = r'//abc001/e$/Intepub/wwwroot/Apps/Dev/Region-1'
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for dir in dirs:
        print dir
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating through directories with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587118/iterating-through-directories-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this.

```py
import os
rootdir = r'//abc001/e$/Intepub/wwwroot/Apps/Dev/Region-1'
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    if 'config.json' in files:
        dirs[:] = []
        print(os.path.join(rootdir, subdir, 'config.json')
```

Comment: print (os.path.join(rootdir, subdir, 'config.json'))