# Looping over subdirectories and their subdirectories and creating a dictionary

Tags: python, windows, directory

How would I loop over subdirectories in a directory, returning them like this:

```
dirlist = {
  "area": ["square","circle"],
  "line": ["line"]
}
```

There's no need for fancy stuff, because I'm sure that there's only a subdirectory and a sub-subdirectory, nothing past that.
There are multiple subdirectories and multiple sub-subdirectories for each subdirectory.

Comment: use ```os.walk()```

Comment: You do not have any directories.  You have a dictionary.  Each value in the dict contains a list.  How do you iterate over a dict?  This is in any tutorial on dicts -- along with how to access its value.  Similarly, once you have that value, any tutorial on lists will teach you how to iterate over those.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link to half solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587118/iterating-through-directories-with-python)

> The actual walk through the directories works as you have coded it. If
> you replace the contents of the inner loop with a simple `print`
> statement you can see that each file is found:
>
> ```
> import os
> rootdir = 'C:/Users/sid/Desktop/test'
>
> for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
>     for file in files:
>         print os.path.join(subdir, file)
> ```
>
> If you still get errors when running the above, please provide the
> error message.
>
> ---
>
> **Updated for Python3**
>
> ```
> import os
> rootdir = 'C:/Users/sid/Desktop/test'
>
> for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
>     for file in files:
>         print(os.path.join(subdir, file))
> ```

Other half is simple, you don't find a file as given in the link, you juts record the names of the subdirs in arr and the main subdir in as a key in dict, then to
make the arr the value of key.