# Pass directory to python script as command line argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

I have a few sub-directories that live in the same folder as my python script. I am trying to run the script inside one of the sub-directories.

example:

```py
$ script.py subdirectory
```

Is there a way to pass in the sub directory at command line

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what exactly you're doing?

Comment: You have two sub problems. 1. How to pass command line arguments, 2. How to change directory in the program. Search for these separately, you would be able to put it together.

Comment: You can use ```python``` and then space and the path to your file. It can be done with the file too

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587118/iterating-through-directories-with-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-subdir", "--subdirectory", help="enter subdirectory name")

params = parser.parse_args()

subdir = params.subdirectory

## and continue your code using subdir as the used subdirectory name
```

So when you want to run:

```
script.py -subdir SUBDIRECTORY_NAME_HERE
```